# How to update/upgrade a deployed rancher workload?

Tags: docker, rancher

Last week I discovered [Rancher](https://rancher.com) (2.0) and it really helped me to get my own cluster up and running in a couple of minutes.

I deployed a really simple website:

- I created the docker image (`example:latest`)
- Pushed the image to my docker registry
- Created a new Rancher workload for this image

Today I made some changes to this simple website and built the image again. Now I want to deploy my new image (`example:latest`). How can I do this?

What's the right way to upgrade a running workload in Rancher 2.0? Unfortunately there is not much documentation about Rancher 2.0 out there.

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: check this official doc, https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/k8s-in-rancher/workloads/upgrade-workloads/

Answer (score 3):

With the Workloads tab selected, you will see a list of of your current workloads. Select 'Edit' from the options dropdown at the far right. The page that comes up is the 'Upgrade Service'. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click the Upgrade button.

Answer (score 0):

With the newer versions of Rancher, the above information is no longer valid.

The current method is to find the Deployment and select "Redeploy" from the 3 dots menu.